# .NET Send a HTTP 400 with response body

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-services

I'm working on an AJAX based submit of a form which will also be made available as an API for other applications.  Therefore I am validating the Request that comes into the Save routine to ensure that fields contain relevant data (numbers in numeric fields, dates in date fields, etc)

I believe it should be best practice to return a HTTP 4xx response code if the user submits nonsense data in the Request but if I set the HTTP Status code to 400 then I get no Response body text.

I've inherited the HTTPException to track specific details of the error which I would like to relay to the client, and the API interaction will all be conducted via JSON.

My code is (roughly):

```
try
    //my request validation code
catch e as myRequestLoadException
    response.write("{")
    response.write("""errormessage"": """ & e.message.replace("""","\""") & """")
    response.write("""errortext"": """ & e.tostring.replace("""","\""") & """")
    response.write("}")
    Response.StatusCode = e.myStatusCode
end try
```

The response I get either using Postman or the Chrome developer tools is:

"**Bad Request**"

If I remove the line where I set the Response Status code and repeat the test then I get the response I am expecting.

So is it IIS, the .net framework or even Chrome witholding the response body?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is IIS, which by default does not allow custom content for responses reporting errors. To allow that, make the change in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

Taken from [this article](http://develoq.net/2011/returning-a-body-content-with-400-http-status-code/)

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply! Perfect... Google kept giving me results for the "other side" of the equation, people trying to deal with receiving a 400.